# How can I write a linq query for this?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I need to write following query in Linq to SQL but not sure what is the best way of doing, given it has two derived tables. Any suggestions.

```
SELECT A.ID  
FROM  
(   
    SELECT *   
    FROM Orders   
    WHERE ProductID = 5  
) A  
JOIN  
(  
    SELECT CustomerID, MAX(Price) Price   
    FROM Orders   
    WHERE ProductID = 5  
    GROUP BY CustomerID  
) B  
ON A.CustomerID = B.CustomerID and A.Price = B.Price
```

Comment: What LINQ statement do you have so far? You should try LINQPad if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var b = (
    from o in db.Orders
    where o.ProductID == 5
    group o by o.CustomerID into og 
    select new {
        CustomerID = og.Key
        Price = Max(og.Price)
    }
);
var a = (
    from o in db.Orders
    join p in b on new {a.CustomerID, a.Price} equals 
            new {b.CustomerID, b.Price}
    where o.ProductID == 5
    select a.ID
);
var r = a.ToString();
```

These two links are invaluable when forming things like this:

- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688085

Comment: Why are you using a union?  The OP's query is attempting to find orders with the max price.  A union will not help with that.

Comment: You are correct.  I mis-read the question.  Updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Can you simplify this with LINQ, especially if you use method syntax instead of query syntax.

```
orders.Where(o => o.ProductID == 5)
    .GroupBy(o => o.CustomerID)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Where(o => o.Price == g.Max(m => m.Price)));
```

My advice when writing LINQ, do not simply attempt to convert a SQL statement exactly.  Think about the desired result and develop a solution designed for LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

```
var result = from a in context.Orders
             join b in (context.Orders.Where(o => o.ProductID == 5).GroupBy(o => o.CustomerID).Select(g => new { CustomerID = g.Key, Price = g.Max(o => o.Price)))
                 on new {a.CustomerID, a.Price} equals new {b.CustomerID, b.Price}
             where a.ProductID == 5
             select a.ID;
```